# How can I put all the cities under the same state in a map while I am taking input from the user?

Tags: java

I have to take input from the user in CSV format (area,city,state, pincode). I have created `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`. Output should have State name in the first line and each city name along with the count of address in the city in the next lines. A sample of input and output is like in the added image.

Input and Output Sample Picture

[image: 1]

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> address1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of address:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            Map<String, Integer> address2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            System.out.println("Enter the address:");
            String input[] = br.readLine().split(",");
            if(address2.containsKey(input[1])) {
                address2.replace(input[1], (address2.get(input[1]) + 1));
            }
            else {
                address2.put(input[1], 1);
            }
            address1.put(input[2], address2);
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Number of entries in city/state wise:");
        ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>(address1.keySet());
        ArrayList<Object> data2 = new ArrayList<Object>(address1.values());
        for(int i = 0; i < address1.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = data.get(i);
            System.out.println("State:" + obj + "\n");
            for(int j = 0; j < data2.size(); j++) {
                Object obj2 = data2.get(j);
                System.out.print("City:" + obj2 + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: I would probably create POJOs for the information before processing it. That way it's more extensible and easier to maintain

Comment: [*How do I ask and answer homework questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/642706)

Comment: You can make your own code more readable, if you choose different names for your map: `address1` and `address2` would better be named something in the pattern of *valueByKey*, e.g. `countByCity` instead of `address2`. Also `data` and `data2` are not very helpful for us (and *you* ) to understand the existing code. Regarding the `n`... usually one-letter variable names are only (if at all) good for loop counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, the below code assumes that all input, entered by the user, is valid.

Consider using class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) for getting input from the user.
(More explanations after the below code.)

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int n = stdin.nextInt();
            stdin.nextLine();
            Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> states = new HashMap<>();
            int count;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter address: ");
                String line = stdin.nextLine();
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                Map<String, Integer> cities = states.get(fields[2]);
                if (cities == null) {
                    cities = new HashMap<>();
                    states.put(fields[2], cities);
                }
                if (cities.containsKey(fields[1])) {
                    count = cities.get(fields[1]);
                }
                else {
                    count = 0;
                }
                cities.put(fields[1], count + 1);
            }
            for (String state : states.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("State: " + state);
                Map<String, Integer> citys = states.get(state);
                for (String city : citys.keySet()) {
                    System.out.printf("City: %s Count: %d%n", city, citys.get(city));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code in your question, you are creating a new `address2` map for each line entered by the user. When you create a new `Map`, it is empty, i.e. it has no entries. You want to create a new `address2` map only if there is no entry for the *state* in the address entered by the user, otherwise you want the existing `address2` map. If `address1` map does **not** contain an entry for the *state*, then method [get](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) returns null. Similarly for `address2` map: if it does not contain an entry for the city, its `get` method will also return null.

Also refer to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) regarding using class `Scanner`.

Here is a sample run of the above code:

```
3
Enter address: Avocado Ave,Newport Beach,california,92660
Enter address: Beachwalk,Honolulu,Hawaii,96815
Enter address: Hana Highway,Maui,Hawaii,96815
State: Hawaii
City: Honolulu Count: 1
City: Maui Count: 1
State: california
City: Newport Beach Count: 1
```